# Excel If statement evaluating multiple cells for substrings

Tags: excel

Need to populate a cell with "YES" or "NO" based evaluating content of multiple cells.  Can get if statement to work when evaluating a cell with a substring that matches the criteria, but get a value error if substring does not match.

```
=IF(OR(G23 ="DUP",AW23 <> "",SEARCH("BFC",D23)),"No","YES")
```

Tried the follow statement:

```
=IF(OR(G6 ="DUP",AW6 <> "",SEARCH({"BFC","AOG"},D6)),"No","YES")
```

where one of the two search text exist in the cell, but still get value error.  The cells in the column for the substring search have several value that need to be evaluated.

Comment: Search returns a number so you can use `isNumber(search(...))=true`

Comment: What does your data look like?

Answer (score 0):

As `SEARCH` will always return an error when the value it's looking for is not found, you are best off using `ISERROR` before each of your `SEARCH` functions and just flip the value if true from what you currently have. For example, `=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("BFC",A1,1)),"Yes","No")` will show "Yes" when "BFC" is not found in `cell A1` and "No" when "BFC" is found in `cell A1`.

(Answered on phone so couldn't format)

Answer (score 0):

Change to this and it should work:

```
=IF(OR(G23 ="DUP",AW23 <> "",ISNUMBER(SEARCH("BFC",D23))),"No","YES")
```